# How to add a query string to redirect_uri of facebook login button?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have a Facebook login button and I set redirect_uri to my local URL. I need to pass some value with redirect_uri.

Any idea of doing it?

Comment: Hi Nilaa, try to be more specific with your problem. I am too lazy to write general discourse on this topic.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `state` parameter to send whatever extra parameters you want to the redirected URL:
`Optional. An opaque string used to maintain application state between the request and callback. When Facebook redirects the user back to your redirect_uri, this value will be included unchanged in the response.`

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/